# Row_number skip values

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, row-number

I have a table like this:

[image: 1]

The idea were to count only when I have "Include" at column `include_appt`, when it finds NULL, it should skip set is as "NULL" or "0" and on next found "Include" back to counting where it stopped.

The screenshot above I was almost able to do it but unfortunately the count didn't reset on next value.

PS: I can't use over partition because I have to keep the order by id ASC

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please also show your desired results.

Comment: Please do not show codes in screenshot. Copy & Paste in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the DENSE_RANK() with the columns you have hidden (--*,):

```
SELECT
    row_num AS id,
    include_appt,
    CASE WHEN include_appt is not null
    THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) 
        + 1 
        - DENSE_RANK() OVER(
            PARTITION BY /*some hidden columns*/ 
            ORDER BY/*some hidden columns*/) 
    ELSE NULL
    END AS row_num2
FROM C
ORDER BY row_num
```

Then the result will be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoWEw.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to prevent row numbers being added for NULL/0 values, why not try a query like this instead?

```
SELECT
    row_num AS id,
    include_appt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
        ORDER BY (SELECT 0)
    ) AS row_num2
FROM C
WHERE ISNULL(C.include_appt, 0) <> 0
ORDER BY row_num
```

I would recommend reconsidering the column names/aliases you want to have displayed in your final result to avoid confusion, but the above should effectively do what you are wanting.

Comment: Because i need also to return 'include_appt' NULL values as well

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a `partition by include_appt` as in another answer below, yet after playing around with the query plans I've decided that it is still worthwhile to consider this slightly different approach which might offer a performance boost. I believe the benefit is gained by being able to use the clustered index without involving a sort on the `flag` column:

```
select id, flag,
    case when flag is not null
        then row_number() over (order by id)
               - count(case when flag is null then 1 end) over (order by id)
        else 0 end /* count up the skips */ as new_rn
from T
order by id
```

Examples (including a "reset" behavior): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c9f4c187c494d2a402e43a3b24924581

Performance comparison:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=719f7bd26135ab498d11c786f1b1b28b

Answer (score 0):

You need a `PARTITION BY` clause

```sql
SELECT
    row_num AS id,
    include_appt,
    CASE WHEN include_appt IS NULL
      THEN 0
      ELSE
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY include_appt ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
      END AS row_num2
FROM C
ORDER BY row_num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, include_appt,
CASE WHEN include_appt IS NULL THEN 0
  ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY include_appt ORDER BY id ASC)
  END AS row_num 
FROM #1 ORDER BY id asc
```